# Simple Database Design - Many to many? - First database (newbie)

Tags: mysql, database-design

This is my first database I am designing.

However I am getting confused on the many to many relationships.

I have a products table, each product can have inventories in many different warehouses. So one product can have many inventories (in different warehouses)

> Table 1 - 
> products 
> PK
> code | name | cost_price
>
> Table 2 - (Many to Many Bridging table)
> product_inventory
> PK                                   PK
> prod_code (foreign key of products.code) | inv_code (foreign key of >products.code)
>
> Table 3 - 
> inventory
> PK
> inv_code (auto increment) | warehouse_code (FK of warehouse.code) | >inventory_count
>
> Table 4 -
> warehouse
> PK 
> code | warehouse_name

My big questions is: is this correct? and 2: does table 3 need product.code linked to it? or is it already linked through the bridging table? (product_inventory) If it is linked, what is an example of an SQL query to input an inventory for a product, so that Table 2 populates to link it all back so later I can do a join to get the inventory for the product again.

Any tips are well appreciated!!

Does every primary key need to have a foreign key? I.E should inventory.code be a foreign key to product_inventory.inv_code? or do only doubles (not the original need to be the foreign key) if so which should be the copy (foreign key) the bridging table or the inventory table inv_code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why have product_inventory at all?

inventory

```
prod_code (foreign key of products.code) | warehouse_code (FK of warehouse.code) | >inventory_count
```

Comment: Because I thought many to many relationship needed a bridging table?

Product can have more than one warehouse with different inventory per product and warehouses can have more than one product inventory?

Comment: Why do you think you need a many to many.  A product has zero or more warehouses.   What you you need to do that is not satisfied with the design in my answer.

Comment: So it would be acceptable to have
Product 1 | warehouse 1 | inventory 1<br>
Product 1 | warehouse 2 | inventory 4<br>
Product 1 | warehouse 3 | inventory 4<br>
Product 2 | warehouse 1 | inventory 1 etc?

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I see you are right, thankyou for your help. if it was many to many would that be the correct way of doing it though?